# How do I reset proxy in terminal to automatic if not connected via proxy

Tags: command-line, proxy, environment-variables

I tried to reset proxy of the terminal by some commands but it doesn't happen and automatically switches back to this proxy 172.16.0.16 (which apparently was my college proxy).

I checked in my system settings.I don't understand why this is recurring.
Please be comprehensive.Also I further would like to know how to bypass proxy server since I couldn't access any of the ubuntu repositories as they were blocked in my college's proxy settings as is Ubuntu's homepage.

Thanks for your time.
 [image: Terminal snapshot]

For
`sudo ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` 
      It displays a different set of options where proxy is not listed.I am on 12.10,if this should help any.I put a snap of the terminal after the above command has been entered.
[image: ls Command entered]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Ubuntu 12.10 will set proxy settings both in `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` when you set proxy from GUI (Network Settings).

### Check your apt settings

```
grep -Hnri proxy /etc/apt/
```

will list out the current proxy settings used by `apt` in the following format.

```
filename:linenumber:proxy-setting
```

If you see any output, it corresponds to `apt`'s proxy settings. They will have to be cleared.

```
sudoedit <filename>
```

will allow you to edit the corresponding configuration file. Copy the existing contents somewhere in case you need to restore them, and delete or comment the lines that look like
`Acquire::<protocol>::proxy=<your proxy here>`
(Add // at the beginning of a line to comment that line. Commented lines are ignored.)

Save the files, close the text editor, and retry. If the problem persists,

### Check global default environment.

```
grep proxy -i /etc/environment
```

Should list any proxy settings that are applied globally. If you need to clear them,

```
sudoedit /etc/environment
```

will fire up the text editor. Lines that start with # will be ignored, so add a # before those lines that mention your proxy settings. Save the file and retry.

### Cleaning the user environment

It is possible that the systemwide configuration is clean but `apt` is picking up proxy settings from the user's environment. `sudo`in certain configurations by default, or when explicitly passed `-E` as an option, preserves the environment.

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

should list out any current environment proxy settings. `unset <variable>` can be used to unset or clear a variable. Unset all `<protocol>_proxy` variables. If they are automatically being set, you might comment out the corresponding entries from `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.pam_environment`

(Those are the most common files that contain the entries. All of them can be searched at once using `grep -Hni proxy ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.pam_environment`  )

Comment: Too bad,neither of them work.I am via a broadband connection,only the browsers are functional.

Comment: Try my updated answer. Notice the `i` option to grep which does a case insensitive search.

Comment: Well i did not complete the last bit _Cleaning the user environment_ But today it seems to magically work.Probably some code fixed itself :| What if i had to undo the operation ?  Will changing in Network GUI again assign the required proxy in the future ?

Comment: Yes. Changing the setting from GUI will revert all the above changes. Just make sure you apply them system wide.

Comment: I've tried clearing the variables, but when I close and restart the terminal all of my proxy values are reset to http://192.168.2.1:8080/ - Why is this happening?

Comment: They are being set due to some configuration file. Check ~/.profile ~/.bashrc, ~/.pam_environment, /etc/environment to see if any of them is the cause. If the problem persists, [join us on chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.iasptk.com/how-to-change-system-proxy-settings-from-terminal-in-ubuntu-1204precise

**How to change system proxy settings from terminal in ubuntu 12.04(Precise)**

Configure Ubuntu desktop/laptop to use your proxy server from terminal.

**Enable proxy setting from terminal in ubuntu 12.04**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

Note:- change Host IP and port setting with yours.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '192.168.1.1′
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
```

**Disable proxy setting from terminal in ubuntu 12.04**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

Comment: This would be the preferred way to set/clear proxy. The GUI (network proxy) does an equivalent job by using Gsettings bindings. However, this sets user level entries and apt may remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

`app-get` proxy setting is store at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20proxy`

Also the filename may be something like **20proxy** .

Attention: You need `root` permission to change or remove the file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` .

This might be work :

> $sudo ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

```
00aptitude    15update-stamp  20proxy                99update-notifier
00trustcdrom  20archive       
01autoremove  20changelog     50unattended-upgrades
10periodic    20dbus          70debconf
```

> $sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20proxy~

if you can't find the file directly , search for `Acquire::http::Proxy` like this:

> find /etc/apt/apt.conf.d | xargs grep "Acquire::http::Proxy`

Since the content of the file which set the proxy should be like so:

> Acquire::http::Proxy "http:172.16.0.16:3142";

Some time the environment variable is set for it `http_proxy`, so do this:

> export http_proxy=

Comment: This won't help sir,please guide me via steps.I can't access the list,the command `$sudo ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` shows me another list