# Wget command error (Error parsing proxy URL http://localhost:4001 : Bad port number.)

Tags: proxy, wget

I was trying to download and install a package using terminal(wget) that i get this error:

```
Error parsing proxy URL http://localhost:4001 : Bad port number.
```

I think it's because of bad installation of JonDo package cause i remember default port number(4001) from Windows version of JonDo!But i don't know how to fix this?
Unfortunately i don't know even how to find package a remove(uninstall) it?

```
aaaa@ubuntu:~$ set | grep -i prox
HTTP_PROXY='http://localhost:4001 '
http_proxy='http://localhost:4001 '
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
      -p --http-proxy --no-http-proxy\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` can ignore your jondo proxy settings using the `--no-proxy` option:

```
   --no-proxy
       Don't use proxies, even if the appropriate *_proxy environment
       variable is defined.
```

Comment: It worked thanks. How do i remove those proxy settings?

Comment: It really depends if you want to keep jondo or not. You could check the files detailed in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/222985/32239) to start.

Answer (score 0):

You have figured it out correctly.

`*http://localhost:4001 : Bad port number*` error is caused by JAP client *anon-proxy*.

It can be removed by typing the following command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge anon-proxy
```

Alternatively, The package *"anon-proxy"* can also be removed from the synaptic package manager

Answer (score 0):

Scan the local host, and type this in the terminal:

```
 nmap -v -A http://localhost
```

and then at the output you see all the open port, and you can try them all and it might work fine this way.